# Parsing: a sentence from Russell's The History of Western Philosophy

Tags: sentence

> The Persian satrap at Sardes represented that he intended to rebel
>   against the Great King, and would pay vast sums for the help of
>   Polycrates, who went to the mainland for an interview, was captured
>   and crucified.

My parsing:

*The Persian satrap* is **S**ubject.

**S**ubject represented that (**Clause A**).

**Clause A**:

**S** intended to do sth, and (**S**) would do sth for the help of Polycrates, (**Relative clause B**), was captured and crucified.

My question: is "was captured and crucified" part of **Relative clause B**?

Comment: @Margana I’ve rolled back your edit since it basically nulled the question. The whole question is whether it is in fact “who […] was captured and crucified”, or whether the relative clause ends after “interview”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet. You're right, Janus. I misread the original. Thanks

Comment: That sentence doesn't seem grammatical - who is the 'was captured and crucified' meant to refer to?

Comment: Russel was never an easy read, when he was trying to be "academic".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your parsing is correct.

“Was captured and crucified” is part of the relative clause of which Polycrates is the subject. It was Polycrates who went to the mainland for an interview, and it was Polycrates who was there captured and killed—probably impaled—and then crucified. (See for example the part about his death in his [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycrates).)

If we ignore the content and knowledge that Polycrates was the one who was crucified, it is *just about* possible to read the sentence in a different way, with the satrap as the subject—but that makes for an awkward sentence:

> The Persian satrap represented that he intended to rebel against the Great King, and would pay vast sums, was captured and crucified.

The fact that there’s an *and* before “would pay vast sums” makes what would then be a list of four complement clauses very unusual. If we have a list of four things, we don’t usually say, “A, and B, C and D” unless they form two pairs [A + B] and [C + D]. If the *and* before “would pay vast sums” had not been there, the opposite would be true, and the correct reading (that Polycrates was captured and crucified) would become highly awkward.